# My MediaWiki Site Won't Serve Stylesheets as text/css

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

I recently installed **MediaWiki version 1.19** on a Debian server running Apache. I am able to access pages successfully. However, the pages come up unstyled. I cannot load the stylesheet in my browser.

Using Firebug, I've compared the response headers for my site to those for a Wikipedia page. The relevant difference appear to be that my site serves up the stylesheet url (`load.php?debug=true&lang=en&modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared|skins.vector&only=styles&skin=vector&*`) as `text/html` content-type and Wikipedia serves it up `text/css`.

I suspect that it has something to do with the Apache rewrite module settings. I found [this page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread%3aProject%3aSupport_desk/CSS_is_not_loading_properly) discussing the issue and offering various suggestions for the rewrite rules. I've tried them all without any success.

One additional detail that may be relevant: I'm running the MediaWiki code out of the `/var/www/wiki` directory on my Debian server. I've updated the appropriate MediaWiki config settings and added these lines to the `.htaccess` file in `/var/www`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/$ /wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/wiki/*$ /wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/wiki/(.+)$ /wiki/index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What can I do to get Apache to serve up this `load.php?debug=true&lang=en&modules=mediawiki...` link as `text/css` content?

Comment: Nope, this is MediaWiki's responsibility - the PHP script should emit the proper header. Strange, this should work - not serving content type should be treated as a bug and fixed

Comment: Just upgraded to latest version of MediaWiki (1.20.2) on the off-chance that it was a bug or regression in the version I installed. But issue persists. So I'm pretty confident it's not a bug in MediaWiki but something wonky in my configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a basic configuration problem. I had the `DocumentRoot` in my Apache configuration set to `/var/www/wiki`. I had the `wgScriptPath` in `LocalSettings.php` set to `/wiki`.

Changing `wgScriptPath` path to `""` and getting rid of the .htaccess rules solved the problem.